# TFS Teams Inheriting a Project's Iterations

Tags: tfs

I have a single TFS project and many teams within this for each product the company makes.  This works well as people can move between teams easily.

All teams are following the same sprint cycle and I create iterations at the project level for these.

How can I force each team to automatically inherit each iteration created rather than having to visit each teams admin page individually to add the iterations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not any way to directly assign project iterations to all teams in project iteration page under work in web portal.

From the Iterations page, you can add and select the iterations that will be active for your team.

For multiple teams you have to visit each teams page and select/assign each iteration in project or new your owns individually for your team requirement.

[image]